# Fixed div inside scrolling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I need to make the main of my site that has `980px width` and `500px height` (class="main") be fixed only when the mouse is over a scrolling div and has a `height of 1500px` and a `width of 100%` (class="container-scroll"), that is inside other div with `height of 500px.` (class="container")

Pretty confused, right?

I made a fiddle, I'm almost there, the problem is that if I set up the main to fixed, it will scroll with the page , not just inside the div

This is my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/8oj0sge4/1/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-scroll">
            <div class="main">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding-top: 380px;
    }
    #wrapper .container {
        border: 1px solid green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    #wrapper .container-scroll {
        height: 1500px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
    #wrapper .main {
        width: 980px;
        height: 500px;
        background: black;
        overflow: scroll;
        /*position: fixed;*/
    }
```

Comment: So you want to enable scrolling in the inner div only when the scroll starts from this div. Otherwise you still want to main page to scroll. Is that correct? Because I'm a bit confused with what you really want to do

Comment: Sorry, i dont have a good english, i know haha.. Yes! And when the scrolling is enable, i need the .main to be fixed..

Comment: I'm racking my brain since yesterday , all I do not worked.. --'

Comment: does this need to be css only or can it use JavaScript? I know your tags say jQuery, etc. but you don't seem to be exploring those solutions...

Comment: Js can be used @DrCord

Comment: I guess I don't understand how your fiddle isn't what you want, it seems right from your specifications...Will you please describe what is wrong with your current fiddle explicitly?

Comment: the main is not fixed in my fiddle DrCord

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're after: is it that you want `.main` to always remain at the top of `.container`, even if the contents of `.container` are scrolled, but to move when the whole page is scrolled?

Comment: i want to make the .main fixed inside the scrolling div (make always appear), but in my current fiddle ->  https://jsfiddle.net/8oj0sge4/1/embedded/result/ is not, because if i change to be fixed, the .main will follow the page scroll, and not the .container scroll

Comment: I do not know if my English is bad or if I'm not explaining right.

I want the MAIN scrolle along with .CONTAINER, but if I set MAIN to = fixed position it will scroll along with the whole page, not just within the .CONTAINER

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want the main div to stay on the top of the parent div?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8oj0sge4/3/ ([full](https://jsfiddle.net/8oj0sge4/3/embedded/result/))

Changes made:

- `#wrapper .main`: Added `position:absolute` ("fixed" to parent)
- `#wrapper .container-scroll`: Added `position: relative` (determines what parent to "fix" to)
- Added an id to the main div (for convenience)

JavaScript code:

```
var main = document.getElementById('main-site');
var maxTop = main.parentNode.scrollHeight-main.offsetHeight; // Make sure we don't go outside the parent

main.parentNode.parentNode.onscroll = function() {
   main.style.top = Math.min(this.scrollTop,maxTop) + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no pure CSS to do that, but you could work around it with some Javascript.

One solution could be to disable scrolling on the inner `div` if the scrolls has been initiated on the `#wrapper`, which is demoed on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qmjmthbz/

Here is the code:

```
var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
var container = $('.container');
var timer;

// Listen to mouse scroll events
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    /* If the scroll is initiated from the #wrapper,
       disable scroll on the container and re-enable it
       100ms after the last scroll event */
    if (target[0] === wrapper[0]) {
        container.addClass('no-scroll');
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            container.removeClass('no-scroll');
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

**Note:** it is useless to use jQuery to achieve that but I am rushing that at a train station. I will provide a better code when I can find more time :-)

Comment: the main is not fixed in this fiddle @floribon

Comment: Sorry @MrBear I guess I still don't understand what you want then. I thought you wanted to scroll "above" the container without catching the scroll event :(

Comment: I do not know if my English is bad or if I'm not explaining right.

I want the MAIN scrolle along with .CONTAINER, but if I set MAIN to = fixed position it will scroll along with the whole page, not just within the .CONTAINER

Answer (score -1):

Basicly I think you can't make the div scroll because the content of the div does not exceed the height of the div. In order for the div to become scroll-able the content should actually exceed the height of the div.

Try giving the div a height of lets say 100px, and insert an amount of text large enough to exceed the 100px height, thus making the div scrollable, and then try if what you want to achieve works.